# Google OAuth Verification and can't add sensitive/restricted scope

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-console-developer

It's has been more than 4 weeks that for OAuth consent screen verification. I haven't received any emails regarding that moreover I can't add some scopes as well and no check box for that too.
I've done the things as per the documentation and is there any wrong.

Here's the problem and any solution:

[image: Google OAuth Scopes]

N.B: I'm not understanding from where I will find 'OAuth clients' they have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Google hasn't made "[all OAuth clients](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)" a hyperlink for you, I just did. :)

**The details**

You should look for the non-HTTPS URIs in each OAuth client listed in the **Credentials** tab of your Google developer account. Here's the link again: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Check each of the OAuth clients on the page...

[image: Google OAuth client list]

... and delete any URIs listed that don't include HTTPS.

[image: Google Client with a non-HTTPS URI]

You may notice that I haven't highlighted `http://localhost/auth`. That's because Google makes a special exception for developing locally.